# Java Thread Pool Executor Monitoring

Tags: java, monitoring, threadpool

The ThreadPoolExecutor class in the Java SE 6 docs has the following [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount%28%29):

> `public int getActiveCount()`
>
> Returns the approximate number of threads
>   that are actively executing tasks.

What is the meaning of *approximate* and *actively executing* here?

Is there any guarantee that, if before, during and after the call to `getActiveCount()`

1. *N* threads have been allotted from the pool for task execution, and
2. None of these *N* threads are available for further task assignment,

the integer returned by `getActiveCount()` will be exactly *N*?

If `getActiveCount()` does not provide this guarantee, is there any other way to obtain this information in a more precise manner?

**Prior SO Questions:**

I have looked at [Thread Pool Executor Monitoring Requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8198584/191776) and [How to tell if there is an available thread in a thread pool in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2657971/191776), but they do not answer my queries.

Comment: Is there any specific necessity for a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, could a factory method such as `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N)` be used in this case?

Comment: @posdef, I need a bounded task queue. Is that possible with a `newFixedThreadPool()`?

Comment: Well, what you get is an executor service with a thread pool of a size you define. Check the javadocs if it meets your needs. I have found them very useful indeed :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that it is *approximate* is because the number could change during the calculation; you're multi-threading. Before the calculation completes a different number of threads could now be active (A thread that was inactive when checked is now active).

When you say "particular time instance" ... that doesn't really mean anything. The calculation isn't instantaneous. The number you get back is the best possible answer given the fluid/dynamic nature of the pool.

If by *chance* the calculation starts and completes while none of the threads in the pool change state, then yes that number is "exact" but only until a thread in the pool changes state, which means it might only be "exact" for 1ms (or less).

Comment: There is no "change of state" in the threads. I have edited the question appropriately.

Comment: My answer still applies; the last paragraph would cover your scenario. The previous paragraphs describe why the docs say *approximate* - in many cases your particular state doesn't exist where the pool is not in flux while the calculation is made.

Comment: Brian -- I *think* in the current JDK implementation, there is actually a global lock which means the number of threads won't change while enumerating them. But the API definition obviously leaves open the possibility that this won't be the case in other/future implementations.

Comment: @Neil - Yeah, with these you really don't care about a particular JVM's current implementation; I didn't even go look.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're possibly confusing things by introducing a notion of "rejoining the pool" that doesn't really exist in the implementation of ThreadPoolExecutor.

Each worker thread sits continually waiting for a task (it effectively sits on top of a blocking queue). Each a task comes in to its queue, that worker is "locked", then any pre-task housekeeping is run, then the actual task is run, then post-task housekeeping, then the worker is "unlocked".

activeCount() gives you the number of threads in the "locked" state: notice that this means that they could actually be conducting 'housekeeping' at the precise moment of calling activeCount(), but that to be counted as 'active', there must be a task actually involved, either about to be, currently, or having just been executed.

Whether that equates with your notion of "rejoining the pool" I'm not sure-- as I say, you seem to be inventing a notion that strictly speaking doesn't exist from the point of view of ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: That explains the `actively executing` part clearly. Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency. I have updated the question to remove it.